# как программно узнать версию android 5.0?

Tags: java, android

Как программно узнать версию андроид? Я нашел в одном из ответов такое решение

```
System.getProperty("os.version");
```

Но мне возвращается почему-то `3.4.0-5508620` хотя у меня стоит Android 5.0... Все остальное что есть в гугле это инструкции о том как через обычные настройки это узнать...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    //тут пятая версия
}
```

Собственно значение типа `int`, содержащие версию текущего устройства хранится в переменной окружения `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

Comment: Да, но это не совсем то что мне нужно... Мне нужно именно получать это значение в переменную, чтоб потом отправить на сервер...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, нужное вам значение хранится в `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`

Answer (score 6):

Делал давно очень, остался пример, попробуйте.

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Button buttonShow = findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    buttonShow.setOnClickListener(v -> textView.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Версия Android: %s (%d)", Build.VERSION.RELEASE, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)));
    //--> Пример вывода: " Версия Android: 4.0.4 (15) "
  }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Показать"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Версия ПО"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]